# Size problem while decoding ciphered text in C

Tags: c, encryption, xor

**[EDIT]**

This is the ciphered text needs to be decoded:

```
bURCUE}__V|UBBQVT
```

I have decoder that successfully fetches ciphered text but convert it to some point. The rest of the encoded message is gibberish. I checked the size of buffer and char pointer, both seem correct, I couldn't find the flaw

Message I expect to see:

> SecretLongMessage

Decrypted message on the screen looks like this:

> SecretLong|drs`fe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUZZ_SIZE 1024


char* encryptDecrypt(const char* toEncrypt, int length)
{
    char key[] = "1011011011";
    char* output = malloc(length + 1);
    output[length] = '\0'; //buffer

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))];
    }
    return output;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buff[BUZZ_SIZE];
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("C:\\Users\\Dell\\source\\repos\\XOR\\XOR\\bin\\Debug\\cipher.txt", "r"); // read mode
    fgets(buff, BUZZ_SIZE, f);
    printf("Ciphered text: %s, size = %d\n", buff,sizeof(buff));
    fclose(f);

    char* sourceString = buff;

    //Decrypt
    size_t size = strlen(sourceString);

    char* decrypted = encryptDecrypt(buff, size);
    //printf("\nsize = %d\n",size);
    printf("\nDecrypted is: ");
    printf(decrypted);
    // Free the allocated buffers

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my C# code that gives cipher

```
String szEncryptionKey = "1011011011";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string EncryptOrDecrypt(string text, string key)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();

            for (int c = 0; c < text.Length; c++)
            {
                // take next character from string
                char character = text[c];

                // cast to a uint
                uint charCode = (uint)character;

                // figure out which character to take from the key
                int keyPosition = c % key.Length; // use modulo to "wrap round"

                // take the key character
                char keyChar = key[keyPosition];

                // cast it to a uint also
                uint keyCode = (uint)keyChar;

                // perform XOR on the two character codes
                uint combinedCode = charCode ^ keyCode;

                // cast back to a char
                char combinedChar = (char)combinedCode;

                // add to the result
                result.Append(combinedChar);
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }


        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String str = textBox1.Text;

            var cipher = EncryptOrDecrypt(str, szEncryptionKey);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\\Dell\\source\\repos\\XOR\\XOR\\bin\\Debug\\cipher.txt", cipher);

        }
```

Comment: You don't allocate enough space for `output` and you don't null-terminate it. `char* output = malloc(length + 1); output[length] = '\0';`

Comment: It's not the cause of any problem, but do note that you can pass `buff` directly to `strlen` and other string functions without first assigning it to a variable of type `char *`, for exactly the same reason that you can perform such an assignment in the first place.

Comment: Also, the loop goes one past the end of the array: `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I edited my malloc and loop as you suggested, however it still decodes wrong like this **SecretLong|drs`fe**

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Should I include my C# because I get different cipher than yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use all characters from

```
char key[] = "1011011011";
```

for your encryption. But the array `key` includes a terminating `'\0'` which is included in the calculation when you use

```
key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))]
```

because `sizeof(key)` includes the terminating `'\0'`.

You could either use `strlen` to calculate the string length or use `key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))-1]` or initialize the array as

```
char key[] = {'1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1' };
```

to omit the terminating `'\0'`. In the latter case you can use `sizeof` to calculate the key index as in your original code

After the C# code was added to the question it is clear that the encryption doesn't include a `'\0'` in the key. `key.Length` is comparable to `strlen(key)` in C, not `sizeof(key)`.

BTW: The variable name `String szEncryptionKey = "1011011011";` in C# is misleading because it is not a zero terminated string as it would be in C.

Note: `strlen(key)` is the same as `sizeof(key)-1` in your case because you don't specify the array size and initialize the array to a string. It might not be the same in other cases.